# Window that opens and closes

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to download an image from a url. For this I added a 'download' parameter in my url. So I just have to call this url with `window.open` to download it.
It works but my problem is that it opens a new tab and closes it automatically. I would like no tab to open. Is there a parameter to add so that it does what I want?

```
public downloadImageJpeg(instanceUID: string, format: string): string 
{
  let url = this.getRootUrl() + mode=download`;
  console.log('url', url);
  window.open(url);
  return url;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to open in new tab then you want to open in existing tab?

Comment: A HTML5 solution would be to use an anchor tag with the download attribute like `<a href="(Link)" download>Download as JPEG</a>"`

Comment: A `window.location.href = url`  should work if the server sends the correct header. Otherwise use  `a` with `download` attribute and trigger a click on it.

Comment: @t.niese
Super you solved my problem in less than 5mn. Thank you very much !!